# Часть речи слова "навстречу"

Tags: морфология

*Идти навстречу. Идти навстречу другу. Идти другу навстречу.

Идти навстречу к другу.  Идти к другу навстречу.*
Конечно, я могу определить часть речи слова "навстречу" в данных словосочетаниях. И определяла. А сейчас вот засомневалась в правильности своих выводов. Хотелось бы сверить свои сомнения с Вашими рассуждениями.

Answer (score 1):

Последние две фразы грамматически не верны. Или убираем "К", или пишем "на встречу".

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь. Примеры есть у Кузнецова.  
Мне это сочетание тоже кажется не совсем удачным лексически, но грамматика тут верная.

НАВСТРЕЧУ. I. нареч.  
В направлении, противоположном кому-, чему-л. движущемуся (при сближении). Бежать, ехать н. Идти н. (также:
содействовать кому-, чему-л., оказывать помощь). II. предлог. кому-чему.  
По направлению к кому-, чему-л. Н. нам шла девочка. Н. судну двигался катер. < Навстречу кому-чему, в зн. предлога.
По направлению к кому-, чему-л. _**Н. к гостям вышел сам хозяин. Пойдём н. к ним?**_
(БТС Кузнецова; курсив мой - b-s)

Answer (score 0):

Ну в первом случае это наречие. А вот дальше - тут от "системы ценностей" зависит. Или собственно предлог или наречие в роли предлога - это уже вопрос веры.

ЗЫ Я сомневаюсь, что "навстречу к" - это лексически удачное сочетание.

~~~~

Продолжаем разговор. Значицца так (С).
В нацкорпусе огромное число примеров на "навстречу к" - Пушкин, Карамзин, Белинский и проч. Удивительно, в их текстах это сочетание смотрится вполне органично. 
Да и в современных текстах эпической направленности ни ухо, ни глаз не режет. Может, действительно считать это сочетание составным предлогом, но несколько архаичным? 
Ничего другого в голову не приходит. Но по крайней мере объясяняет трудности с определением части речи: отвыкли мы от него.

Comment: Я не очень понимаю разницу - предлог или наречие в роли предлога. Давайте лучше в категориях "предлог" или "наречие". Как по Вашей вере? А по более формальным показателям?


О сочетании "навстречу к". Вы считаете, что  как составной предлог "навстречу к " не может быть и это грамматическая ошибка?

Comment: Предлоги во всех случаях (кроме первого).
Нет, граммаьтка тут верная. Но лексически сочетание неудачное. именно здесь. Возможно, в других случаях оно не так слух режет.

Comment: Почему не может быть наречием в последнем случае? К - простой предлог, навстречу - наречие?

Comment: Тогда это другая семантика.  
Типа такой: "Со строны сада шла хозяйка, а из дома насвтречу [ей] к гостям вышел хозяин". *Не судите строго, менее марсианского примера тут не придумать*.

Comment: А позиция слова - до существительного (как обычно у предлога) или после  - для определения части речи в этих случаях роли не играет?

Comment: Не знаю. Думаю, что в данном случае действительно не играет.

Answer (score 0):

Если использовать "навстречу к", то тогда предложение должно выглядеть так:"Идти на встречу к другу".Записать "на" и "встречу" раздельно.

Comment: О существительном речь не идет. Вопрос только о слитных написаниях слова: наречие или производный предлог?